# From whom can one hear havdalah?

Tags: halacha, havdalah, motzei-shabbos, motzi-yedei-chovato

I know that some mitzvas have particularities about who can be yotzei, from whom, and under what circumstances. For example, for kiddush, one is required either to make it or hear it made by one who obligated in kiddush.

Is havdalah the same? Must one hear havdalah made by one who is obligated in havdalah?

--Or do the blessings literally just need to be heard in some form?

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/5861

Comment: http://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Rosh_Hashanah.3.8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is havdalah the same? Must one hear havdalah made by one who is obligated in havdalah?

Generally, yes. However, a minor who has not yet said/heard any form of *havdala* is considered obligated by the rabbis to do so, as is a man who has already said/heard *havdala* without a cup of wine or the like, so the former person can say it for the latter. *Sh'miras Shabas K'hilchasah* 58:19. Similarly, since whether a woman is obligated to say/hear *havdala* by God, by the rabbis, or not at all is a matter of dispute, she cannot say it for a man.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of debate over this question. But it alls tems from the question of whether or not Havdalah is a miswah d'oraita or de'rabbanan.

The Rambam holds that it is a miswah d'oraita (commandment directly from the Torah). And he rules that a woman can say her own Qiddush, and say Qiddush for a man since it's a miswah d'oraita. Therefore, to him, since Qiddush and Havdalah have the same status, a woman can say havdalah for a man.
Sources: http://www.yutorah.org/_shiurim/The%20Mitzvah%20of%20Havdalah%20Part%20I.html
https://torahmitzion.org/learn/women-kiddush-havdalah/

As msh210 has noted, other Rabbis disagree on the status of Havdalah, and therefore the permissibility of women to be able to say it for men.